# How to download the top posts of a hashtag from instaloader

Tags: instagram

I am using instaloader to download hashtag posts using the "download_hashtag" method from the python module. Some context, when you search a hashtag in instagram, it shows up 2 types of posts. The first one is top posts, which are selected by instagram's proprietary algorythm; the second one is the most recent posts.

"download_hashtag" method appears to download the most recent posts and I couldn't find the method or arguments that allow me to download the top posts. Is there any existing method from instagram that I can download the top posts? Or if there is other package that I can use to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `get_top_posts()` sentence from `instaloader.Hashtag` object. It returns the top 9 posts of that Hashtag.